# Line appears on paper each time HTML file is printed

Tags: html, printing, report

My application builds and prints HTML reports using AxWebBrowser.ExecWb method. Lately each time a report is printed a thin horizontal line is printed across it. It's not supposed to be there, it doesn't appear in any preview (Word, browser), but it's always there on the paper, always at the same absolute location and regardless of the printer type. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be anything IMO. A live link to a HTML page would be the very best thing.

Comment: Print some other kind of file on the same printer and see if the line is there. And accept some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Is the "line" actually in the document?

View Source.  Look at the HTML.  Is there an `<hr>` tag?  Are there `<div>` tags that could create the line?  An embedded image?  A boundary on a table with a non-zero width?  Lots of things can do this.

You must look at the HTML.

If the line is not actually in the HTML, then it's out of your control.  It's printer drivers or some such.

Step 2.  If the line is in the document, what did you change between when it worked and "Lately"?  Nothing?  That's what they all say.

You must find everything that changed that leads up to the HTML.

Comment: thank you, there actually was an incorrectly configured <hr> tag that caused this problem